# Convergence of supremum of the series of a signed measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, signed-measures

Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space of finite measure and $f\in L^1 (\mu)$.

For every $E\in \Sigma$ we define:

$$v(E) = \int _ E f d\mu$$

Suppose that $f\in L^p (\mu)$ for some $p \in [1, + \infty)$. Show that

$$\sup _{\pi} \sum_i \dfrac{|v(E_i)|^p}{\mu (E_i) ^{p-1}}  < +\infty ,$$

where the sums are countable and the elements of $\pi$ are all measurable, countable partitions of $X$ (i.e. $X= \bigcup E_i$, $E_i \in \Sigma$, $E_i \cap E_j = \emptyset$ if $i\neq j$) such that $\mu (E_i) > 0$ $ \forall i.$

I dont have any clue on how to bound all of those sums, so I would appreciate very much your help! Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Apply the triangle inequality on $\lvert \nu(E) \rvert$ followed by Hölder's inequality

Comment: It took me some time but your hint helped me ! Thanks!